# Dividing sums with different WHERE conditions

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help in my query. I am trying to divide a  SUM of a column with different WHERE conditions for example

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YR,
  SUM(T1.PRICE) AS COLUMN_1
FROM TABLE_ONE T1
  INNER JOIN SUB_STATUSES status ON status.SUB_ID = T1.ID
  WHERE status.R_SUB_STATUS_CODE = 'COMPLETED'
AND T1.TYPE = 'COMPANY' OR  T1.TYPE = 'SMALL_BUSINESS'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY') DESC

DIVIDE BY 

SELECT 
TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YR,
  SUM(T1.PRICE) AS COLUMN_1
from TABLE_ONE T1
  INNER JOIN SUB_STATUSES status ON status.SUB_ID = T1.ID
  WHERE status.R_SUB_STATUS_CODE = 'COMPLETED'
AND T1.TYPE = 'LOT' OR  T1.TYPE = 'LAND'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY') DESC
```

The first Column returns this :

```
2017    1094
2016    89
2015    95
2014    101
2013    113
2012    173
2011    191
2010    165
```

Comment: Can you show the original tables?

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement instead of a where clause.  Outer query checks divide by zero.

```
SELECT yr, case when column_2 <> 0 then column_1/column2 else 0 end divcol
FROM (
   SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YR,
    SUM(case when t1.type in ('COMPANY', 'SMALL_BUSINESS') THEN T1.PRICE ELSE 0 END) as COLUMN_1,
    SUM(case when t1.type in ('LOT', 'LAND') THEN T1.PRICE ELSE 0 end) AS COLUMN_2
   FROM TABLE_ONE T1
        INNER JOIN SUB_STATUSES status ON status.SUB_ID = T1.ID
   WHERE status.R_SUB_STATUS_CODE = 'COMPLETED'
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(PS.REPORT_PERIOD_END_DATE, 'YYYY')
)
ORDER BY yr DESC
```